# Ajuda com sistema grid do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estou estudando o Bootstrap e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, eu fiz aqui um experimento e gostaria de saber como faço pra quando for minimizado para cel, como alinhar automaticamente as grids, quando minimizo ele fica sobreposto à minha section, a não ser que eu coloque as div com menos margin-top, mas a ideia é de ficar no meio e quando forem minimizadas, se ajeitarem, como faço?

Meu código abaixo

```
 <div class="deve">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
      <div class="branco">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
      <div class="branco">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
      <div class="branco">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
      <div class="branco">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.deve { background: black; width: 100%; height: 380px; position: absolute; }
.branco { background: white; width: 100%; ; height: 130px; position: relative; margin-top: 90px;}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Já tentou utilizar as classes `col-sm-*`?

Comment: Já sim, Anderson, não adiantou, pra entender o que eu quero melhor, quando eu edito o margin-top e coloco 40px e minimizo pro col, fica do jeito que estou querendo!

Comment: Vc está usando margin-top apenas para os blocos brancos ficarem no meio?

Comment: Sim, eu tenho a minha section fixa no tamanho de 380 pixels, e tenho 4 divs dentro dessa section, porém, no col-md se elas estiverem alinhadas no meio, quando forem para col- elas ficam sobreposta devido à altura e largura padrão da section, queria uma solução para à section aumentar a largura automaticamente quando for pra col, ou eu conseguir alinhar as 4 divs dentro da section, estou conseguindo ser claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma class `.valign` e coloque no `container`:

```
.valign{
   position: relative;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
}
```

Os 3 estilos acima irá centralizar verticalmente a `div row` dentro do `container`.

Na `div container` você coloca a classe `valign`:

```
<div class="container valign">
```

**Edit:**

Coloca também um `margin: 15px 0;` na classe `.branco` para ficar espaçado um bloco do outro:

```
.branco {
   background: white; width: 100%; ; height: 130px; position: relative;
   margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: PERFEITO! Muito obrigado Dvd. Só poderia me explicar do por que a position deve ser relative?

Comment: @DiegoDias Por padrão os elementos estão estáticos. O `position: relative;` serve para que se possa movê-los (com top, left etc...)